# How do I require png in HTML using Url-Loader

Tags: webpack

I have been using url-loader in my styles with great success. Now I would like to do the same for HTML files. So if I have something like `<img src="path/to/image.png">` How would I convert that over to using Url loader?

**What I have tried**

```
<img src="${require('../images/my.png')">
```

**Configuration**

```
  {test: /\.html$/, loader: "html"},
  {
    test: /\.less$/,
    loader: "style-loader!css-loader!less-loader"
  },
  {test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader"},
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'url?limit=900000'
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops should have been...

```
{test: /\.html$/, loader: "html?interpolate=require"},
```

Missed that I needed the option.